# How to use reference repo in Gitlab CI

Tags: caching, reference, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are migrating some build jobs from Jenkins to Gitlab CI. We have successfuly used git clone and git submodule with the "--reference" option in jenkins. This makes cloning of big repos much faster and reduces amount of storage per job.

Is there a way of doing the same in Gitlab CI?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the gitlab-runner to only fetch a certain number of commits (smaller number meaning less commits are fetched, so it runs faster) using a variable:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 10
```

This means that the runner will fetch the previous 10 commits when pulling down the repository.

You can also control how the runner retrieves the repository with the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable:

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
```

Fetch is the default, which you can configure in your Projects CI/CD Settings, but you can set it here for individual jobs that should be different than the default. Other options are `clone` and `none` to not retrieve the repository at all (if for example you're building NPM dependencies and them uploading them as an artifact).

Additionally, you can specify extra flags to pass to `git fetch` when the runner retrieves the repository with the `GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS` variable:

```yaml
variables: --no-tags
```

This variable defaults to `--prune --quiet`.
GIT_FETCH_EXTRA_FLAGS:

You can put all of these variables either at the top of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, outside of any job so that it applies to each of your jobs, or you can put it in a single job's definition to apply to just that job, or to override a default set at the top of the file.

There are a few docs that give more detail on these options:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#configure-runner-behavior-with-variables